# Batch file with admin rights start other batch with admin rights?

Tags: batch-file, admin, privileges, rights

I am trying to start a batch file with Admin privileges. But I am trying to start it through a batch file that already got admin privileges. The start should not display any messages or questions.

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: What OS are you using, and what messages are you getting?

Comment: Windows 8.1... I wanna start a batch (uses admin privileges) through a other batch that i manually started with admin privileges. It should start without asking for adminrights!

Comment: Not necessarily - rights inheritance is a subject of some discussion.  Perhaps do a search for that topic?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=p5brU8LyB8XC8gePzIDoBA#q=batch%20file%20inherit%20permissions

Comment: The child batch file should inherit the admin privileges of the parent batch file. Are you saying it does not? Show us your code.